# Check input push button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, input

Basically, I'm trying to create a table that gets user inputs and checks if the answers are correct or not.

I want it to change the 4th column to either correct or incorrect based on the users answer.

Here is what I tried:

```
    <form name="input" action="javascript:void(0);" method="get">
        <table id="compsci-table" style = "margin: auto;">

            <tr>
                <th>Microsoft Office</th>
                <th>Example</th>
                <th>Extension</th>
                <th>Feedback</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Word Processing</td>
                <td>Word</td>
                <td>
                    <form id="form1" method="" action="" onsubmit="return validateAns(wpExtension)">

                            <input type="text" name="wpExtension">
                            <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Check" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>
                    </form>

                        <script>


                            function validateAns(Ans) {

                                if(Ans == "docx")
                                    alert("Correct!");  
                                    $("#formA").submit(function() {

                                    $("#reveal-space1").text("Correct").show();
                                      return true;

                                    });
                                else
                                    alert("Incorrect."); 
                                    $("#formA").submit(function() {

                                    $("#reveal-space1").text("Incorrect").show();
                                      return true;

                                    });

                        </script>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form id="formA" action="javascript:void(0);">
                        <div id="reveal-space1"> 


                        </div>
                    </form> 


                </td>



            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Spreadsheet</td>
                <td>


                    <form id="form2" method="" action="" onsubmit="return validateAns(ssExample)">

                            <input type="text" name="ssExample">
                            <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Check" class="submitbutton aligncenter"/>
                    </form>

                        <script>


                            function validateAns(Ans) {

                                if(Ans == "Excel")
                                    alert("Correct!");  
                                    $("#formA").submit(function() {

                                    $("#reveal-space2").text("Correct").show();
                                      return true;

                                    });
                                else
                                    alert("Incorrect."); 
                                    $("#formA").submit(function() {

                                    $("#reveal-space2").text("Incorrect").show();
                                      return true;

                                    }); 
                        </script>




                </td>
                <td>xlsx</td>
                <td>
                    <form id="formB" action="javascript:void(0);">
                        <div id="reveal-space2"> 


                        </div>
                    </form> 


                </td>
            </tr>
```

Any guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few problems in your code:

- `<form>` should never inside another `<form>`, it's not valid HTML, and you don't need that many forms...
- `id` is unique in html, do not use the same `id` twice
- do not name two different functions with the same name
- `name` such as `wpExtension` refers to the  element, not its value. use `wpExtension.value` instead
- please put `{}` in if condition if it has more than one line

Here is a working demo after cleaned up your code: http://jsfiddle.net/VbCnu/4/

Please have a look and see if you can figure it out :)